# Java Separate string by spaces not surrounded by [ ] brackets

Tags: java, regex

How do I split a string by whitespaces if it is not surrounded with this kind of bracket [ ]

So the string `" book [new interesting book] buy it "` should be split in

```
book
new interesting book
buy
it
```

or

```
book
[new interesting book]
buy
it
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be regex? You can do it **in one iteration** just by counting how many brackets ware before space to determine if that space should be replaced by new line mark or not.

```
String data="book [new [interesting] book] buy it";
StringBuilder buffer=new StringBuilder();
int bracketCounter=0;
for (char c:data.toCharArray()){
    if (c=='[') bracketCounter++;
    if (c==']') bracketCounter--;
    if (c==' ' && bracketCounter==0)
        buffer.append("\n");
    else 
        buffer.append(c);
}
System.out.println(buffer);
```

Out:

```
book
[new [interesting] book]
buy
it
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to use `String.split()` here because it's hard to distinguish between spaces within brackets and spaces outside of them.  Instead, continually `Matcher.find()` against your string until you have exhausted it of tokens.

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\[.*\\]|[^\\s]+)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" book [new interesting book] buy it ");
while (m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(tokens);
// Prints: [ book , [new interesting book] , buy , it ]
```

The regex above ignores leading and trailing whitespace, and grabs: (1) anything, if it is within brackets or (2) any sequence of non-spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed a little bit @cheeken's response, just to improve it a little bit. I decided to include it in an answer because of code formatting:

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\[.*\\]|[\\S]*)\\s*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(" book [new interesting book] buy it ");
while (m.find()) {            
    if (!m.group().matches("\\s*")) {    
       tokens.add(m.group());
    }
}
```

I changed the second part of the pattern in order to use the predefined class of \S instead of his negation and I tested the pattern against the empty string in order to avoid including the initial and final spaces his answer would allow.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "foo [bar bar] foo";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\[|\]");
String[] s = p.split(input);
```

now we have the part left of the [, the part inside the brackets and the part right from the ].
Now you can go trough these parts (if necessary) and split them further.

Comment: Do the '[' and ']' characters need to be escaped, e.g. \[ and \] ?

Comment: Yes, of course.. You should use `\[` and `\]`. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!