# i have goo/foo/[[.//@edit=yes ]/eoo/doo]/coo[another] want to get only goo/foo/coo

Tags: java, regex

I have

`goo/foo/[[.//@edit=yes  ]/eoo/doo]/coo[another]`

want to get only `goo/foo/coo`

I tried `.replaceAll("[.*?]", "");` but this is not working.

Comment: Regex in Java is not right tool to handle nested structures since it doesn't support recursion. Maybe simply write your own simple parser which will count lever of nesting and if you are inside `[..]` braces (including nested ones) simply ignore this text. I mean something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/11089080/1393766

Comment: thanks ! it worked :)